# logical database restore keeps causing mysqld service to stop

Tags: mysql, wamp

I've got a moodle database running on WAMPServer and I'm trying to do a logical backup and restore onto a newer major version of WAMPServer.

The logical backup is 205MB in size and when I try do run `mysql -u root moodle < moodle.sql` the mysqld service stops (specifically wampmysqld64 service) and I get the error `ERROR 2013 (HY000) at line 625: Lost connection to MySQL server during query` (line number can vary).

I've tried breaking the file up into smaller chunks with limited success but there's no guarantee that the same chink will complete or fail when I retest the process.

I'm using the latest WAMPServer (3.2.4.8 64 bits) and the contained mysql version is 8.0.31.

I've already tried the following changes:

- Setting `autocommit = 0` in my.ini config file

I can't find anything online about getting this issue fixed.

Any advise is welcome. Thanks.

**Edit - to feedback on comments etc.**

1. **Service Stopping** The service definite does stop as it this can be seen as no longer running in Services.msc.  I can start it again manually.  Similarly, the WAMPServer icon goes from green to yellow when the service stops.
2. **MySQL Workbench Export** So the MySQL Workbench's "built in EXPORT function" is basically the same of using mysqldump or phpMyAdmin's export function.  It produces an sql file containing all schema and data objects exported as an import script.  It is not exporting that I have a problem with - I have the exported sql script already - it is the importing that is failing.
3. **Timeout** I have tried extending the timeout to 600 seconds but the error occurs in just 10-20 seconds regardless.  Furthermore, a timeout wouldn't cause the service to stop so I don't think this is a timeout issue.
4. **Hardware** I've tried this on the client's test virutal server runing Windows Server 2019.  I've also tested this on my own local virtual server (Hyper-V) running Windows Server 2022 with 12 vcores and 8GB RAM (clean install to try to resolve the issue).  Host CPU is an AMD Ryzen 9 3900 12/24-core processor and 32GB RAM.
5. **Export** See https://justpaste.it/ah81y
6. **This error during data restore sometimes indicates an individual query (probably a long INSERT statement) exceeded the max_allowed_packet size**  This could be possible, although the final line that it errors on is never the same. max_allowed_packet is currently set to 67108864 (400 0000h) = 6.7MB.

When I break up the full sql file into smaller bits (2000 lines for example), sometimes it will execute, and sometimes the service would stop.  For example, having just run it now, the error reported is:

```
CREATE TABLE `mdl_attendance_warning` (
   `id` bigint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `idnumber` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
   `warningpercent` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
   `warnafter` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
   `maxwarn` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
   `emailuser` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
   `emailsubject` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `emailcontent` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   `emailcontentformat` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
   `thirdpartyemails` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `mdl_attewarn_idnwarwar_uix` (`idnumber`,`warningpercent`,`warnafter`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED COMMENT='Warning configuration'
 
 
 Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query 0.188 sec
```

and the previous three statements were:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mdl_attendance_warning`
    0 row(s) affected   0.016 sec
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */
    0 row(s) affected   0.000 sec
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */
    0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s):
 3719 'utf8' is currently an alias for the character set UTF8MB3, but will be an alias for UTF8MB4 in a future release. Please consider using UTF8MB4 in order to be unambiguous.   0.000 sec
```

7. **mysql.log**  I think I am getting these errors being logged immediately prior to the service stopping.  Here are three cases:

```
2023-06-22T15:54:34.376621Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-012646] [InnoDB] File .\moodle\mdl_auth_oidc_token.ibd: 'aio write' returned OS error 0. Cannot continue operation
2023-06-22T15:54:34.377113Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-012981] [InnoDB] Cannot continue operation.


2023-06-22T15:55:13.587552Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-012646] [InnoDB] File .\moodle\mdl_analytics_models_log.ibd: 'aio write' returned OS error 0. Cannot continue operation
2023-06-22T15:55:13.588131Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-012981] [InnoDB] Cannot continue operation.


2023-06-23T15:36:50.345860Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-012646] [InnoDB] File .\moodle\mdl_assign_user_mapping.ibd: 'aio write' returned OS error 0. Cannot continue operation
2023-06-23T15:36:50.346431Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-012981] [InnoDB] Cannot continue operation.
```

I am going to reduce the sql to a manageable size that still causes the error and doesn't contain any sensitive data.  Maybe the error will occur someone else using WAMPServer too?  Thanks

Comment: Try MySQL Workbench to access your MySQL database. I wonder what values your timeouts are set, because maybe the file is "soo big" it timed out and loses connection before its done reading.

Comment: Of NOTE - if you DO use MySQL Workbench, it has a built in EXPORT function where you can click everything you want to be exported from the database, inlcuding any stored procedures, events, and functions.  But the files it creates can be used to import to a new database, in essence an easy and fast way to export a database so you can import it elsewhere.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please.  From new moodle
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 2 minutes UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Look at your MySQL server logs. It often explains what happened.

Comment: Did the service actually stop? If you connect and run `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Uptime';` does it indicate it restarted around the time you got that error restoring the backup?

Comment: This error during data restore sometimes indicates an individual query (probably a long INSERT statement) exceeded the `max_allowed_packet` size. The connection is broken, but the MySQL Server service did not restart.

Comment: Thanks to everyone above who has commented.  I've appended the original question with tests and responses to the above.  Just a reminder - it is importing not exporting that I'm having problems with and the service is definitely "stopping" (i.e. no longer Running in services.msc).  Thanks

Comment: @Chris Walsh   Thanks for posting the requested data.  Analysis in process - may be 48 hours before suggestions posted - funeral attendance planned.

Comment: **NOTE** latest version of WAMPServer is V3.3.0 and can be found at https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions to consider for your my.ini [mysqld] section

```
max_allowed_packet=1G  # from 64M to tolerate max allowed size
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to conserve 90% CPU cycles used for function
```

stop/start retry restore, if still failing,

```
net_read_timeout=300  # from 30 for greater tolerance before timeout
net_write_timeout=300  # from 60 for greater tolerance before timeout
replica_net_timeout=300  # from 60 for greater tolerance before timeout
slave_net_timeout=300  # from 60 for greater tolerance before timeout
```

replica server's my.ini will need same timeout limits.

If still failing please consider posting last 100 lines of error log immediately after failure.

Please view profile for contact info.

You need to manage your fragmented tables that have date_free space greater than 10% of data space used by using OPTIMIZE table name.

Here is a query to assist.

SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME,
CONCAT(ROUND(data_length / ( 1024 * 1024 ), 2), 'MB') DATA_Space,
CONCAT(ROUND(data_free / ( 1024 * 1024 ), 2), 'MB') FREE_Space, create_time,
table_rows, engine, create_options
from information_schema.TABLES
where TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql') and
Data_free > ( DATA_length * .1)
ORDER BY FLOOR ( FREE_Space ) DESC, FLOOR ( DATA_Space ) DESC,
TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
LIMIT 0,512
;